# Approximating a Convex Piecewise Linear Function by Convex Polynomial

Tags: polynomials, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, approximation, piecewise-continuity

I have a convex piecewise linear function defined on some interval $x \in [a,b]$
$$
  f(x) = \max(a_0 x + b_0, ..., a_n x + b_n)
$$

where $n$ is large, too large to calculate quickly when used as a piece of of a larger optimization problem I'm working on in [CVXpy](http://www.cvxpy.org/).

I'd like to understand how to find a "reasonable" convex polynomial approximation $p(x)$ (order $m \ll n$) of that function such that $p(a) = f(a)$, $p(b) = f(b)$ and $p(x) \approx f(x)$ in an $L^2$ sense.

A convex $p(x)$ could then be used instead of $f(x)$ to run quickly run a number of slightly different convex optimizations in real time for users with different needs.

$f(x)$ is fairly well behaved ($a_i$ are evenly-ish spaced and increasing) so I think I don't have to worry too much about corner cases.

Edit: Broader Problem:

The problem is part of properly taking into account trading costs when trading assets in a financial portfolio.

The overall goal is to find a new portfolio $X$ that minimizes the trading costs $TC(X, X^0)$ from our current portfolio $X^0$, costs of being off your ideal portfolio $X^*$ called $CEC(X, X^*)$ and costs in the future if you trade to $X$ which are $FC(X, X^*)$.

$$
\min_X J(X,...) = \min_X [TC(X, X^0) + CEC(X, X^*) + FC(X, X^*)]
$$

where $TC$, $CEC$ and $FC$ are all a bit complicated but nicely convex.  So $J$ is convex and can be solved quickly.

However, I'm making this framework tax-aware so in addition to the other trading costs each asset $x_i$ in the portfolio $X$ has additional costs

$$
TC_i(x_i, x^0_i) = f_i(x^0_i - x_i)
$$

if you are selling $x_i \leq x^0_i$, $TC_i = 0$ if you are buying.  The $f_i$ are of the convex piecewise linear form at the top with the $a_i$'s corresponding to the different tax rates of each tax lot.  This is unfortunately not convex because of the buy/sell difference but can be broken into two convex subproblems.  For the whole problem this gives us 2 to the number of assets total subproblems ($\geq \leq$ for each asset).  This is ok as the number of assets can be reasonable but the number of tax lots $n_i$ for each asset $i$ is often large which can slow the process to a crawl.

I (well CVXpy at least) can solve all the subproblems and therefore the total problem in a reasonable amount of time if the $n_i$ are small, but takes too long otherwise.  I do have all the info I need for the tax problem the night before, however.  So if I can preprocess the $f_i$ into some reasonable convex approximation (polynomial?) the night before I can solve the problem in real time the next day.

Blockquote

Comment: Use Gram Schmidt on a suitable set of basis functions, albeit this would be expensive.

Comment: Similar to this?  http://www.mathematica-journal.com/2017/05/polynomial-l2-approximation  I think that slow is ok as this will be a pre-processing step.  Can I assure the two endpoints with this method?

Comment: Is there someway to assure convexity in the result?

Comment: How large is $n$? What will you do with this function? How do $a_i, b_i$ depend on $i$? Why is it faster to first find an approximation and then optimize over that?

Comment: Great questions.  n can be in the 10s of thousands which is a lot of extra variables for CVXPY.  Especially as the final version is a 14 dimensional optimization.  I've organized a_i to be increasing over the range where that line is the max.   The approximation can be calculated the night before, but the (approximate) optimization must be done in real-time in front of a user and can be done just once and used many times over different users.

Comment: Maybe notify @LinAlg of the comment...

Comment: you should state the full problem, because you may be solving the wrong problem; also state what will be different in each real-time run because now it seems like you can even pre-store the solution

Comment: @LinAlg  I expanded on the motivation a bit, but I'm tied as the full optimization problem would be much too long to fully state.  I fairly sure if I can pre-simplify this function I would be able to solve the full problem quickly enough. 
 The full problem is a version of this optimization with more complicated cost terms including the above piece-wise linear function. http://marriottschool.net/emp/boyer/financeseminar/s07_08/Mark%20Kritzman%20w08.pdf

Comment: Does it have to be polynomial ? what if just a smooth function ?

Comment: Modeling packages like cvxpy are intended to make it easy for you to _specify_ functions. They don't promise that the resulting models will be easy or fast to solve. This seems like a good candidate for a custom algorithm.

Comment: May I ask you to consider offering us a fuller sense of the complete model? So we have $f(x)$ above, which is I assume the objective function, but what are the constraints? I'm afraid it's not clear to me from the paper (which admittedly I'm not going to read through, but if you can point me to an equation...)

Comment: I hope that is enough to give a taste.  So the objective is much larger, but I feel if I can break it down into these preprocessing problems and run them the night before I can get this to work.

Comment: Cvxpy may incur much overhead, especially since you solve many different subproblems; it is possible that directly interfacing a solver is considerably faster. I still do not understand the problem. The number of tax brackets is often small, right? TC looks a bit like $x^3$, right? Then why is $n$ large?

Comment: @LinAlg  TC without taxes is usually modeled as $|x-x^0|^{(3/2)}$ for spread and market impact.  TC's from taxes however depend on the history of when you bought and each lot you sell has a different tax rate depending on capital gains/losses.